# CSS links not being found (Laravel 4, Nginx, HipHop VM)

Tags: nginx, laravel-4, hiphop

I found a ton of answers on here for this question but they don't appear to be working for me. I am trying to link my CSS and JS in my blade template but they are not working.

I used:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
```

Which produces:

```
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mysiteurl.org/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mysiteurl.org/css/bootstrap-reset.css">
    <!--external css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mysiteurl.org/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mysiteurl.org/css/owl.carousel.css">
    <!--Custom styles for this template-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mysiteurl.org/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mysiteurl.org/css/style-responsive.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mysiteurl.org/css/custom.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
```

It seems like it SHOULD go to in the public folder but the CSS is not showing up. I am using nginx and have the root set to public. The site and all the routes work fine but the css is the issue.

I am not sure if this is a Nginx thing, a HipHop thing, or a code thing.

Here is my NGinx conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /var/www/mysiteurl.org/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm ;

    server_name mysiteurl.org;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/mysiteurl.org-access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/mysiteurl.org-error.log error;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files \$uri \$uri/ /index.php?\$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { log_not_found off; access_log off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;      

    include hhvm.conf;  # The HHVM Magic Here

    # Deny .htaccess file access
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why backslashes in `try_files`?

Comment: I took this config from a Laravel/HipHop website since I am new to all 3

Comment: Well, its certainly typo. It should be `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;`